# How to disable dynamic sign up with Open ID provider during client authentication flow?

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth, google-openid

**Background**: I'm using Open ID authentication in my asp.net website. Here is how it works currently - User would pick an Open ID provider from dropdown (google/yahoo/myopenid/etc..) and then click on Login button.  The application would then pass the user to the provider authentication page. On successful authentication and authorization on the open ID provider site, user is directed to my application. So far, so good.

**Problem**: On the Open ID provider authentication page, if the user chooses/clicks Sign Up, then the provider is following its own workflow and the control never returns to my application.

**Question**: Is there a way where I can disable the dynamic registration on provider (i.e., the Sign Up)?, so that, the user would then be required to register with the provider and then use my application? Or
Is there a way that I can get the control back once the dynamic registration is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The OpenID protocol has no such provision and while it would be courteous of a Provider to remember to ultimately redirect their new user back to your site, not all do.